# How can I reduce run time Q12 Project Euler

Tags: java

My code takes way too long to run. What I've tried to do is loop all the way to a large number and then loop ip to it to find it's sum then loop to check the divisors.How do I optimise it?

```
public class Q12
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int answer=5;
        Boolean check=false;
        int sum=0;
        int counter=0;
        int kk=0;
        while(check==false)
        {
            loop:
            for(int i=1;i<50000000;i++)
            {
                sum=0;
                counter=0;

                for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    sum=j+sum;
                }

                for(int k=1;k<sum;k++)
                {
                    if(sum%k==0)
                    {
                        counter=counter+1;
                    }

                }

                if(counter>=501)
                {
                    check=true;
                    break loop;
                }


            }


        }



    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Employ some math for optimizations, e.g. the sum of all integer values between a and b should be easily calculatable without looping.

Comment: You are recalculating the sum from `0` every time you loop through `i`, just store it outside the loop and add `i` at every loop iteration. Also, you don't need to start `i` at `1`. There are more efficient ways to get the factors of a number rather than go through and test them one by one. If you know `2` is a factor for example, than you also know that `n/2` is a factor. Also, you can stop `k` at `sum/2`, as that is the largest possible factor (excluding the number itself).

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not obvious what yours code supposed to do, so I'm doubt what I can optimize there...
2. This portion:

   ```
   check=true;
   break loop;
   ```

   breaks execution and jumps to

   ```
   loop:
   for(int i=1;i<50000000;i++)
   ```

   which will run inner loop with 50000000 iterations again, after `check` was already evaluated. Is that intended behaviour?
3. Here:

   ```
   sum=0;
   counter=0;

   for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
   {
       sum=j+sum;
   }
   ```

   you can use caching. Like:

   ```
   long[] precalc = new long[50000000];

   int answer=5;
   Boolean check=false;
   int sum=0;
   int counter=0;
   int kk=0;
   while(check==false)
   {
       loop:
       for(int i=1;i<50000000;i++)
       {
           sum = precalc [i];
           if (sum == 0) {
               precalc[i] = sum = (precalc[i - 1] + i);
           }

           counter=0;

           ...
   ```
4. Also I suggest you to use `long`-s instead of `int`-s, as there is possible arithmetic overflow.